# Web.config settings

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web-config

I have a web application and it has its default `web.config` with all the needed settings so now I need to create a folder and in that folder I am implementing a Login page using the same membership tables as for the parent application. I am trying to allow certain roles to access that folder, I tried adding a web.config in that folder with the following mark up:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="customers"/>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The issue I am having is that when I add this and I attempt to login, it sends me to the parent login page with a `ReturnUrl` and thats because the parent has this line in the web config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/login.aspx"  timeout="20160" />
</authentication>
```

So i decided to add that to the web.config in the folder but with the correct url:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/pages/customerlogin.aspx"  timeout="20160" />
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="customers"/>
            <deny users="?" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

But now its telling me that this error:

**Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type    'Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.RewriterHttpModule'.**

I guess my question is, what should i be adding to that child `web.config` so it works?, doesnt it inherit from the parent all of the other things it needs?. This is the first time I worked in these kind of issues of web.config settings in a subfolder.

**NOTE (UPDATE) : The folder was converted to an Application**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to inherit from the parent web.config then in your child web.config you can add the following line as the first child element of the config section you don't want to inherit.

## Example child config

```
<system.web>
      <clear />
      <!-- add child config settings here -- >
 </system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say:

```
<deny users="?"/>
```

you are saying that you don't allow user who are not identified to execute the pages before the login.

Only after that login you can evaluate the user role.
Because of that you only should have one login page and based on the roles of the users redirect them to the different sub-site.

If the folder is now an application, it need the entire configuration file.